# How to render property value as a function parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple view that looks like this:

```
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let person of people">
     <h5 #name>{{person.name}}</h5>
     <div #age>{{person.age}}</div>
     <div>
       <button (click) = "getInformation(name, age)">Click me/button>
     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

and in my component I can simply do this:

```
getInformation(name: HTMLElement, age: HTMLElement){

}
```

my question is: Is there a way to use the person.name or person.age directly in my function that is in the view instead of using a template variable? something like this:

```
<button (click) = "getInformation({{person.name}}, {{person.age}})">Click me/button>
```

Comment: What do you want to do in `getInformation` method?

Comment: @WandMaker I just want to get the value of name and age. That is all. I know i can get it if I use a template variable but I would like to use a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have u tried

```
 <div>
   <button (click) = "getInformation(person.name, person.age)">Click me/button>
 </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
getInformation(name: string, age: number) {

}
```

Thanks to @ConnorsFan.

Comment: @CodigoMentor What error are you getting when u use aboce code? Please explain what doesnt work

Comment: Can YOU share a jsfiddle? Lol

Comment: @coderxyz : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp. verify the value you are passing, if its a number. Share your code on stackblitz.com plz

Comment: @coderxyz - You may need to declare the method as `getInformation(name: string, age: number)`.

Comment: @ShashankVivek - I meant the method in his class. Your markup was OK. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan : My bad. i was busy in another work so i didnt mind that as well. Corrected. Thanks again

Comment: I think that the markup should be `getInformation(person.name, person.age)` (as in the original answer).

Comment: @ConnorsFan :D Roger that